# Divide by Zero Simple Program

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {

 Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

 int myCents = 0;
 int myDollars = 0;
 int myQuarters = 0;
 int myDimes = 0;
 int myNickels = 0;
 int myPennies = 0;

 System.out.printf("Please enter the amount of cents below: \n");
 myCents = userInput.nextInt();

 myDollars = myCents/100;
 myQuarters = myCents % myDollars;
 myDimes = myCents % myQuarters;
 myNickels = myCents % myDimes;
 myPennies = myCents % myNickels;

 System.out.printf(myCents + " is equal to %4d", myDollars);
 System.out.printf(" dollar(s), " + myQuarters);
 System.out.printf(" quarter(s), " + myDimes);
 System.out.printf(" dime(s), " + myNickels);
 System.out.printf(" nickel(s) and " + myPennies + " pennies. \n");
}
}
Error:  java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

The error seems to keep popping up. We have not learned if statements for Java as of yet. It is supposed to be a simple program.

Comment: % is modulo, right? That is, the myCents % myDollars = the remainder after doing myCents with myDollars?

Comment: You need to tell us on which line the error occurs and what input is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%` is the [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator. A modulo operation requires first performing division. In Java, like many other programming languages, [an error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) is thrown when an integer is [divided by zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero).

This is the first line that could possibly cause the error, most likely due to zero being input by the user.

```
myQuarters = myCents % myDollars;
```

Answer (score 3):

`myCents/100` is integer divison and so if `myCents < 100`, `myDollars` will be 0. Therefire `% myDollars` will throw your `/ by zero` exception.

Instead try:

```
myDollars = myCents / 100;
myCents = myCents % 100;
myQuarters = myCents / 25;
myCents = myCents%25;
```

etc. (assuming a quarter is 25 cents... I've never used USD)

Answer (score 0):

Any of `myDollars`, `myDimes`, `myNickels` or `myPennies` could be *0* due to the nature of the modulus operator(`%`). Then you use that value to do more modulus operations, which effectively divide by 0 before returning the remainder.

You should add if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should convert your variables to `double`:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

 Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

 double myCents = 0;
 double myDollars = 0;
 double myQuarters = 0;
 double myDimes = 0;
 double myNickels = 0;
 double myPennies = 0;

 System.out.printf("Please enter the amount of cents below: \n");
 myCents = userInput.nextInt();

 myDollars = myCents/100;
 myQuarters = myCents % myDollars;
 myDimes = myCents % myQuarters;
 myNickels = myCents % myDimes;
 myPennies = myCents % myNickels;

 System.out.printf(myCents + " is equal to %4f", myDollars);
 System.out.printf(" dollar(s), " + myQuarters);
 System.out.printf(" quarter(s), " + myDimes);
 System.out.printf(" dime(s), " + myNickels);
 System.out.printf(" nickel(s) and " + myPennies + " pennies. \n");
}
```

This should resolve the issue.

Comment: While this would indeed get rid of the exception, I'm not sure if an amount of "NaN" will really help.

Answer (score 0):

`someNumber % 0` will result in a `java.lang.ArithmeticException`. This can happen in several places of your code. E.g. if the user enters a number below 100 then `myDollars` will be "0" or if the user enters "100" then `myDollars` will be "1" and `myQuarters` will be "0".

As a general advice: Unless you know how to properly debug your code (which I assume you haven't learned yet), you can always use `System.out.println` (or `System.out.printf`) to inspect the values of your variables at a certain point.

In your example you could e.g. move your `System.out.printf` statements right after the calculation of the values to see which value is exactly "0" when the exception is thrown.